# How to open radWindow on top of all frames in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

How to open radWindow on top of all frames. I have 2 frame in my page. 
When open radWindow from a frame, radWindow is showing into same frame. I want to open radWindow on top of all frames. (in center of browser, but no in same frame)

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change javascript code that open radwindow.
 var oWnd = window.parent.radopen('your url', 'modalPopUp');

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" ShowContentDuringLoad="false"
            VisibleStatusbar="false"
            RegisterWithScriptManager="True"
            EnableShadow="True" ReloadOnShow="true" Behaviors="Maximize,Move,Close" ShowOnTopWhenMaximized="true" Width="800px" Height="600px"
            runat="server" Skin="WebBlue">
        </telerik:RadWindowManager>
        <telerik:RadCodeBlock runat="server" ID="rdbScripts">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function ShowWindow() {

                    var oWnd = window.parent.radopen('your url', 'modalPopUp');
                    oWnd.center();
                }


            </script>
        </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

Comment: Just make sure the parent page has a RadWindowManager. You can add a check like

if(window.parent.radopen) {}

You can also use window.top.radopen() in case you do not know how deeply your frames are nested

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You will need to adjust the dimensions to get it where you need and the size you like. Please note that in this snippet the radwindow is showing a page "dataWarning.aspx", you need to change this to pint to your content.

The function:

```
function openWarning() {
            var width = "350px";
            var height = "930px";
            var left = "350px";
            var top = "195px";
            radopen("dataWarning.aspx", "Warning", width, height, left, top);
        }
```

The button:

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="Button11" runat="server" Text="Open Window" OnClientClicked="openWarning" AutoPostBack="false">
<Image EnableImageButton="false" />
</telerik:RadButton>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: NO. I want to open radwindow on top of all frames in page. But no in center of browser

Comment: Just set the position as I said in my answer.

Comment: tank you for answer. I using your solution. But this way, set radWindow just in current frame.I have 2 frame in my page. I want to set radwindow top of all frames, but no in center of screen. Do you understand what I mean?